# datetime picker for Angular 6, Bootstrap4 without fontawesome

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Does anyone know of any datetime picker for Angular 6 / Bootstrap 4 which does not have fontawesome or any other custom font as a dependency, and will work with IE 11?

Comment: e.g. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: cheers, will have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [ng-pick-datetime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime) and replace the fa-icon with any representation you want (another svg, png, etc.)

Simply install it via:

```
npm install ng-pick-datetime --save
```

If you are using Angular CLI, you can add this to your styles.css:

```
@import "~ng-pick-datetime/assets/style/picker.min.css";
```

And instead of (from the examples):

```
<input [owlDateTime]="dt2" placeholder="Date Time">
<span [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt2"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
<owl-date-time #dt2></owl-date-time>
```

You could simply trigger the picker via:

```
<input [owlDateTime]="dt2" placeholder="Date Time">
<span [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt2"><img src="path/to/file.png" alt="dp-icon" /></span>
<owl-date-time #dt2></owl-date-time>
```

Please see [how to use](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime#how-to-use) for more elaborate details on implementing this package in your angular project.

Another idea could be to simply use [bootstraps datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) depending on your preferences regarding UX and design..

Comment: Along with this picker, most of us will face an issue of '@angular/cdk/a11y' package missing. So for this, you need to run `npm install @angular/cdk@^6.3.0` to fix this issue and get it working.